# JSON help in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I wanted to get result like :

```
[{"status":"open","open_time":"0900","close_time":"2100"},
{"status":"open","open_time":"0730","close_time":"2100"},
{"status":"open","open_time":"0730","close_time":"2100"},
{"status":"open","open_time":"0730","close_time":"2100"},
{"status":"open","open_time":"0730","close_time":"2100"},
{"status":"open","open_time":"0730","close_time":"2100"},
{"status":"open","open_time":"0900","close_time":"2100"}]
```

this using json.

Here is my php form:

```
    <div class='form_field'>
<?php
    echo " <table> <tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Opening</th><th>Closing</th></tr>";
        $floatroom_hours =array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');

    for($counter = 0; $counter < 7; $counter++)
    {       echo "<tr><td>$floatroom_hours[$counter]</td>";
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='status' </td>";
                if (isset($_POST['status'])) "value='open'";
                    else "value='closed'";
        echo "<td><input type = 'text' name = 'open_time' class = 'hours'  size='4' maxlength='4' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type = 'text' name = 'close_time' class = 'hours'  size='4' maxlength='4' /><br/></td></tr>";
                $hours['status'] = $_POST['status'];
                $hours['open_time'] = $_POST['open_time'];
                $hours['open_time'] = $_POST['close_time'];

    }
    echo "</table>";

?>

        <?php
        echo form_submit(array(json_encode($hours)=>$floatroom_info->hours));?>
    </div>
```

However I am not getting desired result.

I need some help on this. Can someone share your experience please?

Comment: You have a mistake: `$hours['open_time'] = $_POST['close_time']` should be `$hours['close_time'] = $_POST['close_time']`

Comment: `$hours['open_time'] = $_POST['open_time'];
$hours['open_time'] = $_POST['close_time'];`

See what are u doing ... 

saving CLOSE TIME in OPEN TIME variable

Comment: @Umair: I already pointed that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, your HTML is wrong to start with. At this moment your only posting one `open_time`, `close_time` and `status`

The HTML should be changed first to this :

```
for($counter = 0; $counter < 7; $counter++) {     
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '  <td>'.$floatroom_hours[$counter].'</td>';
    echo '  <td><input type="checkbox" name="status['.$counter.']"'. (isset($_POST['status'][$counter]) ? ' checked' : '') . ' /></td>';
    echo '  <td><input type="text" name = "open_time['.$counter.']" class = "hours"  size="4" maxlength="4" /></td>';
    echo '  <td><input type="text"name = "close_time['.$counter.']" class = "hours"  size="4" maxlength="4" /><br/></td>';
}
```

As you see the input will now be posted as an array. Next step is processing the form. Best thing here is to move the logic outside the form. Place this snippet just under the PHP tag

```
<?php 
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        if (isset($_POST['open_time'])) {
            $data = array();
            foreach($_POST['open_time'] as $index => $value) {
                $data[] = array(
                    'status'    => isset($_POST['status'][$index]) ? 'open': 'closed',
                    'open_time' => $_POST['open_time'][$index],
                    'close_time' => $_POST['open_time'][$index],
                );
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have a more question. 
I used to save this string into db by manually like:
`
<?php echo form_input(array(
  'name'=>'hours',
  'id'=>'hours',
  'value'=>$floatroom_info->hours)
 );?>
`

so now how I am gonna change this?

Comment: You will need to take the same aproach and use a foreach around it. You should open this in a new question if you can't solve it with the attempts you tried.